# IntelliJ and Git Branch Name

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I've recently moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ. A challenge as I'm a keyboard shortcut junkie, but that isn't what I'm here about.

I miss having the git branch name shown in the package/project view.

Does anyone know of a way to configure IntelliJ to display what git branch the project is in, so I don't have to keep switching back to the terminal and checking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

As of IntelliJ 11 the current Git branch is displayed in the bottom right corner of the status bar. Moreover, clicking on the branch name displays a nice popup with all available branches, and you can invoke some actions on them.

---

To enable `status bar` follow the below steps :

```
 View --> Appearance --> Status Bar [and click to enable/disable]
```

Comment: ok, but this is not really ideal if you have a multirooted project from dozens of repositories, you don't want to sequentially select them all to see which branch they are at

Comment: @PéterVarga As of IJ, 12.1 this popup displays all repositories with their current branches in a single view.

Comment: I do see the git branch on the Intellij I have installed at work but after 20 mins of digging I can't figure out how to configure it on my home machine. What's the secret?

Comment: @AlexWorden Have you enabled VCS integration for your project? Check if your Git root is configured in Settings | Version Control, and check if your local changes are correctly identified in Changes | Local.

Comment: Ah - you know what this was? The 'status bar' was disabled. Duh!

Comment: I have the status bar enabled, and Git appears to be correctly configured in the Settings of the IDE.  I can't find a way to show the git widget in the status bar. Some of my clone directories have it, some don't. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like exiting and re-entering full screen mode resized the window, allowing the widget part of the status bar to be correctly displayed. Yikes!

Comment: How could i get the Git Branch Name into clipboard?

Comment: I found another way which worked for me:  right click on the location where the git branch info used to appear. You will see branch info unchecked. check that and you will be back in business.

Answer (score 43):

Install IntelliJ Plugin "GitToolBox"

[image]

Comment: Better and more visual than the integrated IntellIJ solution

Answer (score 13):

There are 2 possible scenarios of not displaying git branch name and here is how to resolve them.

1). Firstly, if your entire status bar is hidden or not display currently; So, you can enable it by easily by Tick the Status Bar option like this:

```
View -> Appreances -> Then Tick the Status Bar option
```

[image: Status Bar option]

2).If your problem is still displaying the Status Bar in the IDE though, your GIT branch section doesn't display. Then you can use Status Bar Widget option to enable it also.

```
View -> Appreances -> Ststus Bar Widgets -> Git Branch
```

[image: State Bar Widget option]

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: And an additional way to reveal the same `Status Bar Widgets` menu:  Right-click on any Widget that is currently showing.

Answer (score 3):

As IntelliJ cannot show be my branch I found a way to add the branch to my bash prompt in the terminal. I've added this to my .bashrc file and I get a nice real-time branch indicator.

```
#Git branch prompt
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

function proml {
  local        BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local         RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local   LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local       GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local       WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local  LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  case $TERM in
    xterm*)
    TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
    ;;
    *)
    TITLEBAR=""
    ;;
  esac

PS1="${TITLEBAR}$RED\u@\h:\w$GREEN\$(parse_git_branch)$LIGHT_GRAY\$ "
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
}
proml
```

EDIT: Ignore this prompt. If you need a GIT prompt use http://volnitsky.com/project/git-prompt/

Comment: Does this one update when you switch branches from the command line?

Comment: yes. if you are in a directory that is tracked by git then the prompt includes the current branch.

Comment: It is easy to change your terminal window to a gitbash prompt on windows. Just change the Shell path to : "...Git\bin\sh.exe --login -i"

Comment: Nice. If you prefer Perl: `git branch | perl -ne 'print $1 if /^\* (\w+)/'`

Answer (score 3):

Coming from Eclipse, I was used to that, so I created a plugin for this:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7802?pr=idea

Answer (score 2):

That setting doesn't seem to be available with the current [Git integration in IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html#Git_support).

One workaround would be to start a fake push, because the push Window would then display the current branch.

[image: Push Changes options]

<sup>(just click cancel instead of going forward with the push:

You have the information you were looking for in the first place.)</sup>

Comment: getting on this old issue ... Any idea on how to work around that in IDEA13 now that this window doesnt exist anymore?

Comment: @user1737909 I don't have an Intellig IDEA 13 to test it out right now. It would be best to post a new question with a link back to this one for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to add VCS to the project if not already done
2. CTRL SHIFT A - opens find
3. Type - status
4. Select Status Setting
5. Click on version control
6. It would list out the unregistered projects
7. Select your project then click on + button on the right panel
8. If You have initialized the git in your local then it would not ask for git path.
9. Check the other parameters as per your requirement and then apply.

Congrats, you are done provided you have enabled the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using git.exe from "/bin" folder

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post when googling this issue, so I'll leave my solution even though it's more than 10 years later.

If you cannot find the option "Git Branch" in: View → Appearance → Status Bar Widgets, then it is very likely that you need to trust the project first. If you don't trust the project, it opens in safe-mode and then the widget is not available.

Re-opening the project and trusting the project did the trick for me. More about project security and trusted projects: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-security.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, if someone is looking for a way to see current git branch in intelliJ.

1. Install gitbar plugin [Git Bar Plugin Repo](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8151?pr=)

[image]

2. Enable status bar and look at the bottom right corner , which shows your current branch as well as you can switch branches from there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue whereby I had no git bar or indexing status after moving to IntelliJ 2017.2 - my issue was down to the 'Code Outline' plugin. I deleted it's jar file from `C:\Users\[user]\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\config\plugins` restarted IntelliJ and I suddenly had my git branch info and indexing status back. Maybe this will help someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Just install [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox/) plugin.

**Side note**
The default behavior is to show the file full-path and it will be hard to see the branch names since they're pushed all the way to the right. To solve that you can:

- Go to `File > Settings > Other Settings > GitToolBoxGlobal > Project View` and arrange the ordering of the variables in the left pane. E.g. I use the following order: {status} {branch} {tags on head} {location}; this will display something like `3↑ 2↓ master 1.0.0 /path/to/location`
- Or install [PathHide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8378-path-hide/) plugin to get rid the module path if you don't need it.