# IDEA: How to show what branch one is in?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ Idea, is it possible to show what (git) branch one is currently in?

When can this be changed please?

Comment: Who do you mean with "one"? You cannot see, what another dev currently does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ and Git Branch Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227546/intellij-and-git-branch-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the lower right of the screen and you ought to be able to see the git branch name there. If you can't, it means you have not told IDEA that the code folder is a git repo. Go to settings->version control and you'll see a list of currently registered git roots and a list of those it has detected, but which are not currently registered. You can fix it there.

Comment: Yup. I see it. Thank you Matt